# Saber StatusInfo de puerto serie en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, puertos

Intento establecer la comunicación entre dos ordenadores conectados por puerto serie (COM).

Para abrir el puerto lo hago así:

```
Dim puerto As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
Me.puerto = New IO.Ports.SerialPort
Me.puerto.PortName = Me.cmbPuertoCOM.Text
Me.puerto.BaudRate = 9600
Me.puerto.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
Me.puerto.DataBits = 8
Me.puerto.StopBits = 1
If Me.comEAN.IsOpen Then
   Me.comEAN.Close()
Else
   Me.comEAN.Open()
EndIf
```

El problema llega cuando hay veces que me dice que no puedo abrir el puerto y veo que realmente no está abierto por ningún otro proceso. Esto me ha llegado a pasar incluso tras ejecutar el programa después de encender el ordenador.

En PowerShell con la orden:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort
```

Me dice que el StatusInfo es 2 y por lo que he buscado pone que es *Unknown* (Desconocido). Si voy al Administrador de Dispositivos y deshabilito y vuelvo a habilitar el puerto, cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el código de PowerShell me dice que el StatusInfo es 3.
He actualizado el controlador del puerto COM pero sigue igual. De hecho hay veces que sin apagar el ordenador aunque me abra el puerto y pueda ejecutar el programa, si pasa un tiempo y no estoy haciendo nada en el ordenador hay veces que le vuelve a pasar.

Por si sirve de algo, para cerrar el puerto pongo:

```
Me.puerto.Close()
Me.puerto.Dispose()
```

Me gustaría saber si o bien hay alguna manera de deshabilitar y volver a habilitar el puerto desde código, o poder saber el StatusInfo del puerto ya que ese programa se ejecuta con otro más que también se conecta a otro puerto COM del mismo ordenador y que sí que funciona bien.

El error que me sale al intentar abrir el puerto es este:
[image: Error al intentar abrir puerto COM1]

Comment: Si desde el visual intento abrir el puerto y está en el StatusInfo 2 según PowerShell solo me dice que no se puede abrir el puerto, así que tampoco me soluciona nada que me diga eso si luego veo que haciendo "a mano" lo de deshabilitar y volver a habilitar funciona. Necesito que esto sea automático.

Comment: El puerto serie va en placa o es un usb? Es posible que no está funcionando correctamente?

Comment: El puerto serie está en la placa, si.

Comment: Es un poco extraño lo del estado Unknown, y tampoco estoy muy seguro de porque eso debería influir. De todas maneras, puedes consultar el `Win32_SerialPort` desde tu programa si eso te sirve

Comment: Desde el programa solo he podido saber si el puerto se abre o no, desconozco como saber el estado del puerto o cómo Habilitarlo en caso de que por el motivo que sea esté deshabilitado. Aclaro que el programa no va a estar definitivamente en mi ordenador por eso que intento pensar en todas las posibilidades.

Comment: Consultar el `StatusInfo` es sencillo,puedo ponerte un ejemplo. Lo que no entiendo es cuando te falla esto que es lo que haces. Vas al administrador de dispositivos,deshabilitas el puerto y vuelves a habilitarlo? Has probado en otro equipo para descartar un problema de hardware?

Comment: Leí en algún foro (que no recuerdo) que haciendo eso funcionaba pero realmente no es la mejor solución y lo sé. Si pudieras ponerme un ejemplo, lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como consultar el `StatusInfo` por código:

```vb
Dim Scope As New ManagementScope("\\.\ROOT\cimv2")
Dim Consulta As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort Where DeviceID='COM1'") ' cambialo por el puerto que necesites
Dim Searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Consulta)
Dim queryCollection As ManagementObjectCollection = Searcher.Get
'Obtenemos el valor del primer resultado
Dim status As Integer = queryCollection.Cast(Of ManagementObject).First()("StatusInfo")
Console.WriteLine("StatusInfo : {0}", status)
```

Debes añadir en tu proyecto una referencia a `System.Management`, asi como `Imports System.Management`

**Edit**

Tras varias pruebas, la solución pasa por cambiar el nombre del puerto en el administrador de dispositivos. Intuyo que el puerto que se estaba utilizando de alguna manera estaba mapeado por algun otro dispositivo, provocando el problema detectado.

Comment: Desde el desconocimiento: haciendo esto no se abre el puerto, verdad? Solo comprueba el estado. Lo digo porque como funciona con otro programa más, por poner una comprobación antes de que si uno de los dos puertos que intento abrir no tiene el estado habilitado (el 3), no ejecute el resto del programa.

Comment: @Maria si claro, esto simplemente es una consulta del estado, igual que haces desde powershell. Lo otro a mi nunca creo recordar que me haya pasado. De todas maneras, puedes editar la pregunta y poner exactamente el error que te lanza al intentar abrirlo cuando esta en ese estado?

Comment: @Maria y yo probaría en algun otro equipo, no descartaría en ningun caso un fallo de hardware o quiza drivers

Comment: Ya está puesta la imagen del error. Desgraciadamente ahora mismo no puedo probar en otro equipo pero es muy raro que deshabilitando y volviendo a habilitar el puerto COM funcione y nada más inicie el ordenador no vaya y el StatusInfo sea 2.

Comment: @Maria como una prueba a ciegas...podrías probar a cambiar el numero de puerto? es decir, si el que falla es COM1, puedes probar a cambiarlo a COM3 por ejemplo?

Comment: Poniendo el 6, que es el que siempre va, no hay problema.

Comment: A todo esto, me da error en ManagementScope al igual que en el ObjectQuery. Me falta importar alguna clase?
Actualmente tengo:
   System.IO.Ports   y la que me has dicho de System.Management

Comment: No me refiero a que cambies en tu aplicacion el puerto, si no en el administrador de dispositivos que cambies el nombre del puerto. Ve a puertos com/propiedades/ avanzadas y cambias ahi el puerto a  otro

Comment: Debes añadir en tu proyecto una referencia a `System.Management`, asi como un import. te lo pongo al final de la respuesta

Comment: He puesto el System.Management y sigo igual.
Por otra parte, he probado a cambiar el puerto como me has dicho y ahora el StatusInfo me sale vacío en PowerShell.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59293/discussion-between-maria-and-pikoh).